# Calling a Controller function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is call another function. i have two controler. abc and xyz controler. i want to call abc function in xyz controler. i am trying this..

```
class ABC extends CI_Controller{
   function callme(){
       return "try";
   }
   function anotherfunc(){
       return "try";
   }
}

class CDS extends CI_Controller{
    function callme(){
        return "try";
    }
    function anotherfunc(){
        return "try";
    }
}

class XYZ extends CI_Controller{
   function callme(){
       $user = $this->abc->callme();
       $user2 = $this->cds->callme();
   }
}
```

but it dont work.

Comment: I [googled your exact question](https://www.google.com.au/#q=Calling+a+Controller+function+codeigniter) and heaps of results were returned, did you try any of them at all? Please try and search for solutions yourself before coming here to ask questions that have been asked hundreds of times before.

Comment: i dont want to extends. i wanna just call. because i am call five controler.

Comment: Use the __construct() method and appeal for the parent constructor.

Comment: i dont have just one function.i have  more function.

Comment: That's against the MVC approach (Though CodeIgniter implements sort of MVP). If a method is used repeatedly, it's better to put that in domain layer (Model) instead.

Comment: If functions are used in both places I'm sure there's a relationship with the model that you are using. You should create a method inside the model and call it in both controller actions.

Comment: if your functions are using Codeigniter resources then create a model or library. if they are straight php you can also create a "Helper". http://codeitdown.com/creating-codeigniter-helpers/